# pushing a view controller from presented popup view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller as a popup and in the popup view controller i have a button , onclick of that button i am trying to push a view controller but nothing happens on click.How to do this?

Presnting the view controller as a popup

```
- (IBAction)sendOTPAction:(id)sender {

HMResetPasswordViewController *resetPassword = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HMResetPasswordViewController"];
// configure the Popover presentation controller                             
                        resetPassword.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
resetPassword.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-10, 375);
resetPassword.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
resetPassword.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 0;
resetPassword.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
resetPassword.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0);
[self presentViewController:resetPassword animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Trying to push the view controller from popup view controloer

```
- (IBAction)resetButtonAction:(id)sender {

HMLoginViewController *HMLoginViewController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HMLoginViewController"];
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:HMLoginViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Simple, Your HMResetPasswordViewController should be embedded in UINavigationController. You don't have a navigation controller and trying to push some other controller on navigation.

Comment: @Imad is correct, embed the view controller that you are presenting in a Navigation Stack, then try to push. Your problem will be solved. :)

Comment: sorry, but "pushing" on a "presented" ViewController is not a good design. Try presenting instead of pushing, that will result in a better User Experience

Comment: @Imad,@iPeter If i embed the `HMResetPasswordViewControlller` inside a `UINavigationController` and present it, it will be displayed in fullscreen not a popup and i want it be displayed as popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After presenting, if you want to use navigation stack then you have to create new navigation controller :

```
  - (IBAction)resetButtonAction:(id)sender {
     HMLoginViewController *HMLoginViewController= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HMLoginViewController"];  
     UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HMLoginViewController];
     [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES];
     }
```

After HMLoginViewController, now you can push to other `UIViewController`

Comment: how to pop back from HMLoginViewController?